# Getting error Record updated successfully Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on array

Tags: php, fatal-error

```
<?php 

    getdata();

    function getdata(){     
        $server="";
        $dbHost = "localhost";
        $dbDatabase = "h_php";
        $dbPasswrod = "";
        $dbUser = "root";
        $mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPasswrod, $dbDatabase);
        // Check connection
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
        } 
        $sql = "SELECT * from items";
        $result = mysql_query($query);      
        if(!$result) die("Oh crap...: " . mysql_error());
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        for ($j = 0 ; $j <= $rows; $j++)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);                
            $row[1]= $server;
            $command = "nslookup ".$server;
                exec($command, $result);
                $nslookup_result="";
                foreach($result as $line){
                $nslookup_result.= $line."<br> ";   
                }
            updatenslookup($server,$nslookup_result);
        }
        $mysqli->close();   
    }   

    function updatenslookup($url,$nsresult) {
        // Create connection
        $dbHost = "localhost";
        $dbDatabase = "h_php";
        $dbPasswrod = "";
        $dbUser = "root";
        $mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPasswrod, $dbDatabase);
        // Check connection
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
        } 
        $updatesql = "UPDATE `items` SET `description`='".$nsresult."' WHERE `title` ='".$url."'";

        if ($mysqli->query($updatesql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";

        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error;
        }

        $mysqli->close();

    }
?>
```

Comment: Mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` is bad practice. correct that.Use `mysqli_*` functions only

Comment: tried with mysqli_* in both function. but getting same error.

Comment: well I'll ignore you current issue and point out your SQLInjection vulnerability `UPDATE items SET description='".$nsresult."'` and your lack of using `escapeshellarg` on this line `exec($command, $result);`  You also have this backwards `$row[1]= $server;` because  I don't see where server is defined as anything but an empty string.  But if it was right then you `SELECT * from items` from you compromised table, and inject them right into shell commands, which is probably a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

This bit makes no sense to me:

```
 function getdata(){     
    $server="";  //<---------- set here
    $dbHost = "localhost";
    $dbDatabase = "h_php";
    $dbPasswrod = "";
    $dbUser = "root";
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPasswrod, $dbDatabase);
    // Check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT * from items";
    $result = mysql_query($query);      
    if(!$result) die("Oh crap...: " . mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    for ($j = 0 ; $j <= $rows; $j++)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);                
        $row[1]= $server;  //<---- sure you want to do this
        //your basically setting $row[1] = '' on every iteration
        //so your command below is "nslookup " because $server = ''

        $command = "nslookup ".$server;
            exec($command, $result);
            $nslookup_result="";
            foreach($result as $line){
            $nslookup_result.= $line."<br> ";   
            }
        updatenslookup($server,$nslookup_result);
    }
    $mysqli->close();   
}
```

It seems to me this bit `$row[1]= $server;` is backwards.

But lets not forget the SQLInjection issues here:

```
 function updatenslookup($url,$nsresult) {
    // Create connection
    $dbHost = "localhost";
    $dbDatabase = "h_php";
    $dbPasswrod = "";
    $dbUser = "root";
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPasswrod, $dbDatabase);
    // Check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    } 
    $updatesql = "UPDATE `items` SET `description`='".$nsresult."' WHERE `title` ='".$url."'";

    if ($mysqli->query($updatesql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";

    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    $mysqli->close();

}
```

Specifically this stuff:

```
 function updatenslookup($url,$nsresult) {
    //  ....
    $updatesql = "UPDATE `items` SET `description`='".$nsresult."' WHERE `title` ='".$url."'";
   //  ....
 }
```

The big issue with it is I can inject whatever I want into this table, then you take that data and shoot it right into

```
  exec("nslookup ".$row[1], $result); //simplified  $server = $row[1] + exec("nslookup ".$server)
```

So in theory I can (or may be able to) inject my own command line calls into exec, at least to some extent.  I'm not sure all what someone could do with these issues, what the worst case would be, but I would avoid it in any case.

There is no way for me to know where the data for `updatenslookup($url,$nsresult)` comes from or if its clean, but it doesn't matter. One reason to prepare the sql is to have the security right where the issue is so you can clearly tell by looking at just the query if its safe or not.  And you don't have to worry about missing some piece of data that could sneak in there.

You should use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) at the very least, and clean up the SQL vulnerabilities by preparing your queries.

As far as this `Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on array`, I don't even see a call to `fetch_assoc()` in your code.  Maybe I missed it but all I see is this `$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);` for reading data, which is procedural where you use the OOP in the other code .  which is irritating .. but I get it, which is why I only use PDO now...

Etc..

I always feel bad when I shred up someones hard work, but I would be remiss not to mention such a big security hole.

Cheers.